# How to fix "Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement" error thrown by Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram, puppeteer, chromium

I am creating a bot for posting something every day on Instagram, and I want to use creator studio from Facebook. The script below works fine:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  var username  = require('./config')
  var password  = require('./config')
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const ig = await browser.newPage();
  await ig.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  })
  await ig.goto('https://business.facebook.com/creatorstudio/');
  await ig.click('.rwb8dzxj');
  await ig.waitForSelector('#email');
  await ig.type('#email', username.username);
  await ig.type('#pass', username.password);
  await ig.click('#loginbutton');
  await ig.waitForSelector('#media_manager_chrome_bar_instagram_icon');
  await ig.click('#media_manager_chrome_bar_instagram_icon');
  await ig.waitForSelector('[role=presentation]');
  await ig.click('[role=presentation]');
  await ig.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
  await browser.close();
})().catch(err => {
  console.log(err.message);
})
```

but when I continue and add:

```
await ig.waitForSelector('[role=menuitem]');
await ig.click('[role=menuitem]');
```

I get this error:

> "Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement"

Comment: are you sure [role=menuitem] exists in the DOM

Comment: it's in body so logically yes :/

Answer (score 3):

The error caused by the `click` and `hover` methods called on an `ElementHandle` can be mitigated by ensuring the element is "in view" separately from the method (despite [the docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) stating that the method "scrolls it into view if needed", seems like sometimes the element does not become visible).

Assuming the element is indeed attached to DOM - you can check that via [`isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) property, try using something like this (the sample is in TypeScript) - [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) should make sure the element is centered on:

```js
const safeHover = async <E extends ElementHandle<Element>>(
  elem: E
) => {

  await elem.evaluate((e) =>
    e.scrollIntoView({ block: "center", inline: "center" })
  );

  await elem.click();
};
```

Note that the sample uses `elementHandle`'s [`click`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions) method, not `Page`'s. Since you call [`waitForSelector`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.5.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) before clicking, use the returned `elementHandle`:

```
//...
const pres = await ig.waitForSelector('[role=presentation]'); 
pres && await safeHover(pres);
//...
```

Also, these Q&As may prove useful:

1. [Puppeteer in NodeJS reports 'Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857070/puppeteer-in-nodejs-reports-error-node-is-either-not-visible-or-not-an-htmlele)
2. [Puppeteer throws error with "Node not visible..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57939222/puppeteer-throws-error-with-node-not-visible)